# How to suppress certain .bib fields (e.g. year) only for certain entry types (e.g. inproceedings)

Tags: biblatex, biber

How can I suppress the year from appearing in the bibliography for entries of type `@inproceedings`?  In my specific case the year is implied in the booktitle (e.g. FOCS '09) so it is redundant when I need to save space.  I found http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=11447 and the "second solution" looks promising but I am not sure how to translate it to only suppress the year for one type of entry. I am guessing `\ifentrytype` might be helpful. I am using `biblatex`+`biber`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{inproceedings}{%
    \clearfield{year}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@inproceedings{B09,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  editor = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2009},
  title = {Bravo},
  booktitle = {FOCS'09},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it would be that straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

Or, you can do this before the data even gets to biblatex. Assuming biber 0.9.8+; put this in your biber:conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_type>INPROCEEDINGS</per_type>
        <map_step map_field_set="YEAR" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```