# biblatex: don't show pages attribute

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I would like to remove the "pages" attribute from `.bib` files.

[image: biblatex output]

I tried to pass `\usepackage[usepages=false]{biblatex}`, which seemed the logical way to do it, based on the documentation, but it does not work -- is it possible to disable them?

Comment: The `usepages=false` option seems to be unknown  for `biblatex`

Comment: See also [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864) and [How to suppress certain .bib fields (e.g. year) only for certain entry types (e.g. inproceedings)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23086/35864). You only need to know that pages is a "field" and thus `\clearfield` applies.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is unknown. My point was that the documentation has `useauthor`, `useyear`, and says to use `use<name>` for other fields. But it does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove (disable) particular fields, lists or names with

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}
```

Use `\clear<type>{<typename>}` where `<type>` stands for `list` or `name` and the `<typename>` is the name of the bibtex field you want to disable.

Comment: For some reason, this did not work for me and I had to use `\AtEveryCitekey` instead of `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: Indeed, @Rastapopoulos. I think this should be a separate answer.